# music loop does not work properly in java android

Tags: java, android

I do 15 repetitions of music with a 2 minute music sound, which means I will play 30 minutes of music. but why at the 7th minute the music suddenly stopped? What causes the loop to not work and the music to stop.

public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

```
int count = 0; // initialise outside listener to prevent looping


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String song = (String) extras.get("song");
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, this.getResources().getIdentifier(song, "raw", this.getPackageName()));
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);//
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Memulai Suara Alam....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        int maxCount = 15;
        @Override 
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

            if (count < maxCount) {
                count++;
                mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            } else {

                mMediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        }

    });
    return startId;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    mMediaPlayer.release();
}
```

}

Comment: possible that the OS kills the service after some minutes, try to use foreground service to avoid getting killed.

Comment: thanks bro for our keyword, i use getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); same with our answer